# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS Update breaks Wireless Adapter : Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377

Tags: 18.04, wireless, atheros, inspiron, adapter

I have run into a problem. I recently updated my Ubuntu partition (dual-boot with Win10) to 18.04.3 LTS on my Dell Inspiron 17 3000 laptop. Upon restart, the OS no longer recognizes my wireless adapter. Running `lspci | grep -i "Wireless\|WiFi"` produces:
`02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)`
Running `dmesg | grep -i firmware` produces:

```
[     0.135169] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[     0.208518] ACPI : [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
... (psmouse and dmc normal messages, irrelevant to problem)
[     17.269597] ath10k_pci 0000:02:00.0: firmware ver WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 api 6 features wowlan,ignore-top crc32 42e41877
```

Running `rfkill list all` produces:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Running `uname -a` produces:
`Linux user-ubuntu 5.0.0-31-generic #33~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 10:20:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`
If there is any more information you need, please tell me; I am still a n00b. (I was actually using this partition to teach me Ubuntu)
Thank you!

EDIT:
User heynnema told me to try switching to the 5.0.0-29 kernel, which appeared to fix the problem. The problem did not reappear when I switched back. However, I was asked to produce new output:
Command `dkms status` did not produce an output.

Command `sudo lshw -C network` produced:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 07
       serial: d8:d0:90:2b:77:f4
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 ip=192.168.1.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c1304000-c1304fff memory:c1300000-c1303fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 31
       serial: a4:fc:77:1b:a0:a7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=5.0.0-31-generic firmware=WLAN.TF.2.1-00021-QCARMSWP-1 ip=192.168.1.144 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:c1000000-c11fffff
```

Command `ls -al /boot` produced:

```
total 105068
drwxr-xr-x  4 root root     4096 Oct  5 10:52 .
drwxr-xr-x 25 root root     4096 Oct  5 13:09 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   224422 Sep 12 13:00 config-5.0.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   224447 Sep 30 18:23 config-5.0.0-31-generic
drwx------  4 root root     4096 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x  5 root root     4096 Oct  5 10:51 grub
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 40223093 Oct  4 21:54 initrd.img-5.0.0-29-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 40265800 Oct  4 21:54 initrd.img-5.0.0-31-generic
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   182704 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184380 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   184840 Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw-------  1 root root  4290085 Sep 12 13:00 System.map-5.0.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  4294610 Sep 30 18:23 System.map-5.0.0-31-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8707832 Sep 12 13:01 vmlinuz-5.0.0-29-generic
-rw-------  1 root root  8769272 Sep 30 22:27 vmlinuz-5.0.0-31-generic
```

Comment: If you boot using an older kernel from the GRUB menu, does the wifi work?

Comment: Yup, choosing 5.0.0-29 fixed the problem!

Comment: Edit your question and show me `dkms status` and `sudo lshw -C network` and `ls -al /boot`.

Answer (score 0):

This happend to me too, with Dell Wireless WLAN 1530 Half MiniCard (with proprietary drivers tick mark set during installation). After the update, it stopped working.

Booting with grub selecting older kernel 5.0.0-23 made it work again.